# convex decompositions of the sphere

Tags: co.combinatorics, dg.differential-geometry, convex-polytopes

Consider a decomposition of the sphere $S^n$ into convex pieces (that is, every cell of the cell decomposition is convex, in particular, is contained in a hemisphere).  Consider the $k$-skeleta of this cell-decomposition, and for each of them define $A_k$ to be the $k$-dimensional volume. Now, the question is, are there good (whatever that means) lower and upper bounds for the $A_k$s, given a bound on, say, $A_0?$

Answer (score 3):

You can get some bounds using Crofton formula.
It semms that the optimal bound is
$$A_k\ge \tfrac12\cdot(n-k+2)\cdot\mathrm{vol}_k\mathbb S^k$$

The lower bound on $A_k$ does not seem to change when you increase $A_0$.

Comment: Presumably the lower bound does not increase because vertices can coalesce, so we are down to the case of the simplex?!

Comment: Yes, and hopefully the formula is correct.